# Database design for 150 million records p.a. with categories and sub categories

Tags: mysql, database, myisam

I need some help for a MySQL database design. The MySQL database should handle about 150 million records a year. I want to use the myisam engine.

### The data structure:

- Car brand (>500 brands)
- Every car brand has 30+ car models
- Every car model has the same 5 values, some model have additional values
- Every value has exactly 3 fields:

  - timestamp
  - quality
  - actual value
- The car brand can have some values with the same fields
- The values are tracked every 5 minutes -> 105120 records a year

### About the data:

- The field quality should be always 'good' but when it's not I need to know.
- The field timestamp is usually the but at least one value has a different timestamp

  - Deviation: 1-60 seconds
  - If the timestamp has a different timestamp it has always a different timestamp
- Sometimes I don't get data because the source server is down.

### How I want to use the data for

- Visualisations in chart(time and actual value) with a selection of values
- Aggregation of some values for every brand

### My Questions:

1. I thought it's a good idea to split the data into different tables, so I put every brand in an extra table. To find the table by car brand name I created an index table. Is this a good practice?
2. Is it better to create tables for every car model (about 1500 tables)?
3. Should I store the quality (if it is not 'good') and the deviation of the timestamp in a seperate table?
4. Any other suggestions?

### Example:

Table: car_brand

```
| car_brand | tablename | Address     |
|-----------|-----------|-------------|
| BMW       | bmw_table | the address |
| ...       | ...       | ...         |
```

Table: bmw_table  (105120*30+ car models =  more than 3,2 million records per year)

```
| car_model   | timestamp_usage     | quality_usage | usage | timestamp_fuel_consumed |  quality_usage |fuel_consumed | timestamp_fuel_consumed | quality_kilometer | kilometer | timestamp_revenue   | quality_revenue | revenue | ... |
|-------------|---------------------|---------------|-------|-------------------------|----------------|--------------|-------------------------|-------------------|-----------|---------------------|-----------------|---------|-----|
| Z4          | 2015-12-12 12:12:12 | good          | 5%    | 2015-12-12 12:12:12     | good           |  10.6        | 2015-12-12 12:11:54     | good              | 120       | null                | null            | null    | ... |
| Z4          | 2015-12-12 12:17:12 | good          | 6%    | 2015-12-12 12:17:12     | good           |  12.6        | 2015-12-12 12:16:54     | good              | 125       | null                | null            | null    | ... |
| brand_value | null                |null           | null  | null                    | null           | null         | null                    | null              | null      | 2015-12-12 12:17:12 | good            | 1000    | ... |
| ...         | ...                 | ...           | ...   | ...                     | ...            | ...          | ...                     | ...               | ...       | ...                 | ...             | ...     | ... |
```

And the other brand tables..

**Edit:** Queries and quality added

### Possible Queries

**Note:** I assume that the table bmw_table has an extra column that is called car_brand and the table name is simple_table instead of bmw_table to reduce complexity.

```
SELECT car_brand, sum(revenue), avg(usage) 
FROM simple_table 
WHERE timestamp_usage>=2015-10-01 00:00:00 AND timestamp_usage>=2015-10-31 23:59:59 
GROUP BY car_brand;


SELECT timestamp_usage,usage,revenue,fuel_consumed,kilometer 
FROM simple_table 
WHERE timestamp_usage>=2015-10-01 00:00:00 AND timestamp_usage>=2015-10-31 23:59:59;
```

### Quality Values

I collect the data from an OPC Server so the qualtiy field contains one of the following values:

```
bad
badConfigurationError
badNotConnected
badDeviceFailure
badSensorFailure
badLastKnownValue
badCommFailure
badOutOfService
badWaitingForInitialData
uncertain
uncertainLastUsableValue
uncertainSensorNotAccurate
uncertainEUExceeded
uncertainSubNormal
good
goodLocalOverride
```

Thanks in advance!

Droider

Comment: I've removed the SQL Sever tag.  MySQL and SQL Server are separate products, which often require different solutions.

Comment: Regarding questions 1 and 2: keep all records with same structure in single table. Mind that number of brands and numbers of models are variable in time. Keep your table structure independent of their counts. I would also suggest you checking [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and using keys (primary and foreign).

Comment: what does mio means ?

Comment: Sorry. Mio. is the german abbreviation for million ;)

Comment: @miroxlav Thanks. I will keep that in mind and check your link.

Comment: @Droider – oh, you speak German? Then check German version of the article, it is more detailed: [Normalisierung (Datenbank)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalisierung_(Datenbank))

Comment: Please rephrase your discussion of "timestamp"; I don't follow it.

Comment: Perhaps you meant "> 50 brands"?

Answer (score 2):

Do *not* have a separate table per brand.  There is no advantage, only unnecessary complexity.  Nor 1 table per model.  In general, if two table look the same, the data should be combined into a single table.  In your example, that one table would have `brand` and `model` as columns.

Indexes are your friend for performance.  Let's see the queries you will perform, so we can discuss the optimal indexes.

What will you do if the data quality is not 'good'?  Simply display "good" or "not good"?

Comment: I added queries and quality values to my question. But database normalization has some advantages like miroxlav suggested, right? I guess I can save some diskspace with database normalization. You have good point with reducing the complexity because some external developers have database access.

Comment: If you typically limit to a `timestamp_usage` range, consider building and incrementally maintaining Summary tables -- much faster for the queries.

Comment: Those two queries would run just as fast with `INDEX(brand_id, timestamp_usage)` in a single table as with multiple tables.